# MvvmCross.Forms is not installing

Tags: xamarin.forms

During install MvvmCross.Forms into my project it show the following error.

> Error NU1202  Package MvvmCross.Forms 5.7.0 is not compatible with netstandard1.4 (.NETStandard,Version=v1.4). Package MvvmCross.Forms 5.7.0 supports:
>     - dotnet (.NETPlatform,Version=v5.0)
>     - monoandroid70 (MonoAndroid,Version=v7.0)
>     - portable-net45+win8+wpa81 (.NETPortable,Version=v0.0,Profile=Profile111)
>     - uap10.0 (UAP,Version=v10.0)
>     - xamarinios10 (Xamarin.iOS,Version=v1.0)
>     - xamarinmac20 (Xamarin.Mac,Version=v2.0) App1    E:\xamarin\App1\App1\App1\App1.csproj   1

Comment: What version of VS/NuGet are you using? If it is older, you may not have proper support for .NET Standard.

Comment: I am using vs 2017 latest version